# How to set SMTP settings for each email on the fly?

Tags: django, django-email

We can configure SMTP settings globally by defining these variables in the `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'SMTP_HOST'
EMAIL_PORT = 'SMTP_PORT'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'SMTP_USER'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'SMTP_PASSWORD'
```

I want to set these parameters different for each email. How can I define the SMTP settings on the fly? I mean just before the sending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EmailMessage` class provides you with this option

First step is to configure your email backend

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend
connection = EmailBackend(
    host=your_host, port=your_port, username=your_username, 
    password=your_password, use_tls=True, fail_silently=fail_silently
)
```

Then all you have to do is use your `connection` settings

```
email = EmailMessage(
    subject=subject,
    body=body, 
    from_email=from_email, 
    to=[list_of_recipents, ], 
    connection=connection
)

email.send()
```